# Add exception to an invalid SSL certificate website sending HSTS header

Tags: firefox, ssl, hsts

When visiting a not properly configured website sending a HSTS header, firefox is unable to add a certificate exception; which can make developer's life a hell, as you don't always get choose where do you need to develop/make changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome is currently unable to add a certificate exception at all and the only browser i found that is being able to override this was Firefox with this hack.

- turn firefox off
- go to your profile folder. In windows, it's located in `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\{someid}`
- delete `SiteSecurityServiceState.txt`
- turn it back on